# Existence of timelike curve in a particular set up.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

I encountered online the following exercise:

*Let $M$ be a Lorentz manifold of $\dim(M)=n$, and let $\psi:\Sigma\to M$ be a spacelike submanifold of dimension $n-2$ embedded into $M$.
We will identify $\psi(\Sigma)\subset M$ with $\Sigma$.
Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to M$ be a null geodesic with $\gamma(a)=p\in\Sigma$, $\gamma(b)=q\in M\setminus\Sigma$, 
and $\gamma'(a)\perp T_p\Sigma$.
Such a geodesic will be called a null geodesic normal to $\Sigma$.
Then we define the  null second fundamental form $\chi$ of $\Sigma$ at $p$ relative to $L=\gamma'(a)$ by 
$$
\chi(X,Y) = \langle \nabla_XY,L\rangle ,
$$
for $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(\Sigma)$.
Finally, a point $r=\gamma(s)$ is called  conjugate to $\Sigma$ along $\gamma$
if there exists a nontrivial Jacobi field $X\in\mathfrak{X}^\bot(\gamma)$ along $\gamma$ such that
$$(i) \ \ \ \ \ \ X(s)=0,$$
$$(ii) \ \ \ \ \ \ X(a)\in T_p\Sigma,$$
and 
$$(iii) \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle\nabla_LX,V\rangle=-\chi(X,V), \ \forall V\in T_p\Sigma.$$
In the exercise, one is asked to prove that if there exists a point $\gamma(s)$ conjugate to $\Sigma$ along $\gamma$ for some $s\in(a,b)$,
then there exists a strictly timelike curve connecting $\Sigma$ and $q$.*

I would appreciate any tips in order to start the problem properly. Intuitively, this makes sense when I'm making a picture of the set up because we can clearly deform the null geodesic in a timelike one, but I have a lot of difficulties to formalize my idea and I'm a bit struggling to understand why we are defining the null second fundamental form and how I should use it.

Thanks a lot for the help!